# Is it possible to set title for doctrine 2 migration?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, migration

I am using doctrine 2 with Zend Framework 2 while working on the big project. And I have a lot of migrations. I would like to create a migration and name the migration file clearer for developers. Now it is like Version20171118233337.php, and I want something like Version20171118233337_create_post_table.php.

Can I do this?

I have seen that something similar was used in laravel framework.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Hello! 
Yes, I have tried.

`php vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module migration:generate name_migration` 
 or 
`php vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module migration:generate --create=post`

But these examples have returned errors.

Comment: What errors did you have?

Comment: `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  Too many arguments, expected arguments "command". `      
                                                          
`migrations:generate [--editor-cmd [EDITOR-CMD]] [--configuration [CONFIGURATION]] [--db-configuration [DB-CONFIGURATION]]`